# jQuery Mobile 1.3 Panels disables my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, beta, panels

I realise that 1.3 is still a beta realise but was wondering if anyone is having the same issue as myself and solved it.

For the panels to work the page content must be contained within the data-role="content" container.

However, I am using some API's like twitter which call up content into data-role="content" container, and I also have ad tags in the container. Both of these use javascript and both disable the jQuery mobile platform. I can only get either of these features running in the platform with panels enabled from the first data-role="header" container.

Here is an example of my code that is failing. Thanks.

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
<script language="javascript">
<!--
document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="#"></scri'+'pt>');
//-->
</script>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
footer text
</div><!-- /footer -->

<div data-role="panel" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel">
<ul data-role="listview">
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

A panel should appear just after the page div, like this

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
<!-- panel content goes here -->
</div><!-- /panel -->

<!-- header -->
<!-- content -->
<!-- footer -->

</div><!-- page -->
```

Answer (score -1):

You should place the panel code above the header directly under the page div..